# validation of radiobuttons

Tags: asp.net

how to add validation to check whether the user has chosen between two radio buttons? Suppose there are 2 radio buttons; male and female. How can we ensure that the user has selected one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a name for the radio buttons and then use the following

```
function CheckState()
{
    var rad = document.getElementsByName ( "rdToCheck" );
    var isChecked = false;

    for ( var i = 0;i < rad.length; i++ )
    {
        if ( rad[i].checked == true )
        {
            isChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( !isChecked )
    {
        alert ( "Please select an option" );
    }
}

<input type="radio" id="rd1" name="rdToCheck" />
<input type="radio" id="rd2" name="rdToCheck" />

<button id="btn1" onclick="CheckState();">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is tagged ASP.NET, unless I am missing something, wouldn't a [RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) with a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) be ideal ? Seems like the OP is new to web dev, so this may be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property ValidationGroup="radiobuttons" and in your code behind's method, do:

```
Page.Validate("radiobuttons");
if (Page.IsValid)
{
  // do some code
}
```

More info and examples can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwzxc386.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript,

```
if(document.getElementById("ur1stradiobuttonID").checked== false &&
  document.getElementById("ur2ndradiobuttonID").checked== false)
 {
  alert("Select an option");
  return false;
  }
  else
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a javascript validation to the form with an onsubmit and then check the buttons in the javascript function

```
<form onsubmit="return checkButtons();" >

<script>
function checkButtons() {
   if (document.form1.myRadioButton[0].checked != true && 
         document.form1.myRadioButton[1].check != true )
{
    alert('select a button');
    return false;
}

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

my option will be, have one radio checked by default (e.g male). then u do not need to validate whether one has been checked.

Comment: The problem is that this then allows the user to skip the choice as *you've* made the decision for him/her.